# Does exec/execl use the same virtual memory of the parent process?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, process, operating-system

I'm trying to understand how debugger works, so I found that after the duplication of the parent process by fork() operation there are two programs: a debugger and the monitored program as children.
I don't understand how the program is monitored if it isn't in the same virtual memory space

```
if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
    perror("ptrace");
    return;
}

execl(programname, programname, 0);
```

And, this case, how can I attach to a running program?

Comment: On modern operating systems, the debugger and the debugee run in separate address spaces. The details of how to read or write a client's memory from a debugger vary between platforms.

Comment: If you're really curious about understanding the internals of a debugger Simon Brand (aka TartanLlama) has an excellent tutorial on his [blog](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/writing-a-linux-debugger-setup/).

Comment: The debugger monitors the child through `ptrace()` system calls, not by directly reading and writing its memory.  So there is no need for them to have the same memory space.  For instance, if the debugger wants to examine the value of a variable in the child, it doesn't do it by executing a load instruction with the right address, but rather with a `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA)` system call.  The kernel has access to the virtual memory of every process, so it loads the value and returns it to the debugger.